# Implementing treeset data structure store and read in VBA / Python/ Shell

Tags: python, vba, shell

I have a text file like this

```
LEVEL=3  
LEVEL1=CLASS7  
LEVEL2=ROLLNO1  
LEVEL3=MALE  
JOHN,12   
LEVEL2=ROLLNO2  
LEVEL3=FEMALE  
JULIA,11
```

We need to read this file and need output like

```
CLASS7|ROLLNO1|MALE|JOHN|12  
CLASS7|ROLLNO2|FEMALE|JULIA|11
```

1st LELVEL=3 means maximum LEVEL present in the file.
Here LEVEL 1 is common, but in actual data sometimes LEVEL 1 and 3 
can be common when maximum LEVEL is say 7.Basically there is no clear
pre-defined pattern.
I have solved it in VBA using normal array structure but when file becomes
very big and maximum LEVEL becomes more( like more than 10)
it becomes slow.
Then I tried to read more things and came to know using
treeset data structure and iterator kind of things it works fast.
But this things possible in Java.
How we can do it in VBA ?
If possible in shell or python that is also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a little python approache, but very specific on you string formating, with "text.txt" containing your text:

```
f = open( "text.txt", 'r' )
text = f.readlines()
f.close()

d = { }
for line in text :
    pair = line.split( '=' )  
    if len( pair ) == 2 :  # save Levels as pairs in dict
        d[pair[0].strip()] = pair[1].strip()
    else : line without level means time for output
        out = []  # gather the values in here
        try :
            for i in range( 1, int( d['LEVEL'] ) + 1 ) : # number of levels (1-based)
                out.append( d['LEVEL' + str( i )] ) # add every level
        except KeyError :
            pass
        out += line.split( ',' ) # add current line
        out_as_string = '|'.join( out ) # convert to string with "|"
        print( out_as_string )
```

outputs:

```
CLASS7|ROLLNO1|MALE|JOHN|12   
CLASS7|ROLLNO2|FEMALE|JULIA|11
```